# Vim "apprentice" colorscheme background looks too bright in iTerm on Mac

Tags: vim, colors

I'm trying to use the [Apprentice](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice) colorscheme on a Mac running Vim in iTerm 2.1.4.

My `TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`. However, the colorscheme doesn't look like what the web site says. In particular, the web site has an image that shows what the **background color** should look like with my exact configuration:

[image]

But mine looks like this instead:

[image]

The difference in background color is readily apparent and too bright. I looked at `hi Normal` just to make sure the background is set right, and it seems like it is. Putting the images in Photoshop, my background color is not #262626 as it should be but #333333.

Very interestingly, if I ran the Vim inside Terminal.app, the background color shows up fine. So I believe it is an iTerm problem.

Any pointers as to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Apprentice. I, too, use iTerm and I, too, have to face that issue every day.

This is a colorspace issue in iTerm that affects *every* "256color" colorscheme.

The colors used in Apprentice for "256color" terminals are taken from [the semi-standard xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) which maps index `235` (the background color) to hexadecimal value `#262626`, or `rgb(38, 38, 38)`.

As you already noticed, iTerm converted that color to `#333233` (or `rgb(50,51,50)`) which is substantially brighter. It actually performs the same conversion with every other color but it's less obvious because of the sample size (large flat area vs a couple of anti-aliased pixels).

What happens is that the colors are defined in one colorspace, *Generic RGB*, before being used in another colorspace, *Device RGB*:

```
Generic RGB --> #262626 = rgb(38,38,38)
(conversion)
Device RGB  --> #333233 = rgb(50,51,50)
```

Which is *very* dumb, and… there is AFAIK no way to force the terminal emulator to use one space over the other.

There is an "easy" workaround at the colorscheme level, though, which is to use different values that would be converted to the desired ones *only* for iTerm. I've resisted doing that for a long time but this issue obviously affects others so I have no choice but to put that on my TODO list.

Could you [open an issue](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice/issues), please?

--- edit ---

I just pushed a seemingly working fix. Please try it and let me know it it works for you.

--- endedit ---

Comment: So the correct fix is in iTerm and not the colorscheme obviously. The fix works. Thanks. Unfortunate, however.